# Select by location (add to selection) is removing previous selection using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-location, iteration

I am trying to select multiple times from the same layer with different overlapping layers by location using the 'Add to selection' method. However only the last selection on that layer is kept after the script is finished.

Is this a known problem in ArcGIS Pro (2.5.0) or am I missing something in my code?

In ArcMap this used to work without any problem.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import os
prj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
map = prj.listMaps("Map")[0]

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
for group in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses ("GROUP*", "line"):
    layerList1 = map.listLayers("streets") 
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(layerList1[0], "SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH",group, "","ADD_TO_SELECTION")
```

I am iterating over this a number of times depending on the number of groups. In case of features get selected in the first round. But in the second round they disappear and new features get selected.

Comment: Pro 2.5.0 was superseded by 2.5.1 and 2.5.2 in May and June last year, then the 2.6 series ending in 2.6.7, and the 2.7 series ending in 2.7.4. The current release is 2.8.2. If you're asking about bugs, you really ought to be on the terminal fixpack for that major build, but it would probably be better to be asking Esri Tech Support, since if it is a bug, they're the ones who would be reproducing it and forwarding it to Development. However, this appears to be a simple use error: Each inner loop pass clobbers the `layerList1` contents and resets the selection set in the process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I understand correctly what you are saying it should work if I take the layerlist1 out of the loop? This would be a clear difference between ArcMap and ArcPro because I also have it inside the loop for my ArcMap script. Anyway, let me try to take it out of the loop first before I check the Esri Tech Support.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately taking this layerlisst1 out of the loop didn't work, same result. Seems like I have to go to Esri Tech support after all. Still surprises me nobody else seems to have the same experience since I can't find anything about this topic.....

Answer (score 2):

You create a list of layers that are of type *point* and you feed that into the the select by location tool with an additive selection. If you review the help file for the [Select by Location](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm) tool the parameter setting "SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH" works only with lines (read the relationship section) so frankly I'm surprised you get *any* selection. If you are doing a point on line style selection set the relationship to the default INTERSECT relationship.

Comment: Thanks again for looking at my code. My bad again this trimmed code was not correct, sorry for that. Actually in the original code I feed these points into the network analyst tool and in the end I get a line layer that is used in the select by location tool. Edited this in the code and changed to 'line'. The strange thing here is that if I keep these line layers and after the tool finishes I do the exact same thing with the build in Select by location tool, then it works and it keeps the already selected streets and adds the ones from the other line layer.

Comment: There is a lesson here, if you want people to spend their time helping you for free you need to be providing the original code, data and errors. So twice you have said what you are showing is not the real code, how on earth do you think people would be able to help you when you are not showing the real problem? We are not mind readers or magicians!

Comment: I understand that, apologize for that. Problem however here is that the code is very long and it would be actually take much time from people to understand the code.  So believe me that I did trim it to help people to see the actual problem easier. It is also one of the rules of this forum to keep it simple. However, unfortunately also led to some errors I overlooked. Do you have any idea what the problem can be after the edited code? To me it really looks like a glitch in the ArcPro software, but I am not able to find anything about that.